# can't pass the state as a props from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm stacked for a few hours trying to make a todo app by using react + redux.
I was trying on like a hundreds ways and, it looks like I can't get it
Mainly, I'm trying to get my state as a props in my component and I can't everytime when I try to display sth, im receving "undefined"

`

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export const TodoList = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>There's going to be a list of todos.</h1>
            <h2>{this.props.todos}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    todos: state.todos
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
`
```

code looks like that, and here's the reducer aswell.

```
    const todosReducer = ( state = [{
    id: 1,
    content: 'asdads',
    isDone: false
}], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO' :
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: action.id,
                    content: action.content,
                    isDone: action.isDone
                }
            ]
        case 'DELETE_TODO':
            return state.filter(todo => {
                return todo.id !== action.id
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default todosReducer
```

and then here's the combineReducer function , because I want to add some filters later on.
And actually im marking it as todos but it won't work

```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import todosReducer from './todos';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todos: todosReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Can anyone of you good boys explain a correct way for me ?

Comment: todos should be an array, you need to map over it to display individual properties. Apart from it, the rest of the code look fine

Comment: const TodoList = ({ todos }) => { return <h2>{todos}</h2> } . You can't get this.props in functional component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass props as an argument to the functional component,
otherwise the component has no idea where the identifier is declared thus it is undefined.

Also you need to use props.todos instead of this.props.todos as you are using a functional component instead of a class component.

```
export const TodoList = (props) => {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>There's going to be a list of todos.</h1>
        <h2>{props.todos}</h2>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: as pointed by @Shubham Khatri you also need to map over the array and render the list

For example:

```
{props.todos.map((todo) => {
    return <h2>{todo.content}</h2>
})}
```

You can also use the short hand syntax to auto return the value.

Comment: Omg , i've got this, in case of sitting 10h before the code I was importing components, into files in curly brackets.. hahahaha, thank you guys